# How to set a image on Navigation right bar button item?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

i want to set a navigation controller's right bar button item to image so i write a code like as

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"]];
image.frame=CGRectMake(0, 25, 35, 40);
UIBarButtonItem *customButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:image];
customButton.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi"];
[customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"]];
```

it is like as i want but then button was not clickable.any solution for that????